# Function checkVector(2) returns error in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, match, shapes

I want to match two different contours, especially Mats of Hu moments, but function Imgproc.matchShapes() returns error:

```
contour1.checkVector(2) >= 0 
&& 
contour2.checkVector(2) >= 0 
&& 
(contour1.depth() == CV_32F || contour1.depth() == CV_32S) 
&& 
contour1.depth() == contour2.depth() in function cv::matchShapes
```

So, I have two Mat of Hu moments, returned from function  Imgproc.HuMoments():

```
H1 = Mat [ 7*1*CV_64FC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0xf8ec790, dataAddr=0xc572c00 ]
H2  = Mat [ 7*1*CV_64FC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0xf8bcf70, dataAddr=0xc5dafa0 ]
```

Then I convert them to CvType.CvType.CV_32FC1 with function:

```
H1.convertTo(H1, CvType.CV_32F);
```

But it also returns error, so I think it is because H1.checkVector(2) = -1. But how should I solve it?

```
Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1936: error: (-215) contour1.checkVector(2) >= 0 && contour2.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (contour1.depth() == CV_32F || contour1.depth() == CV_32S) && contour1.depth() == contour2.depth() in function cv::matchShapes
]
at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.matchShapes_0(Native Method)
at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.matchShapes(Imgproc.java:7543)
at sample.Contour.MatchTemplate(Contour.java:264)
at sample.Controller.OnButtonMatchTemplate(Controller.java:167)
... 86 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
```

Comment: Just grammar improvement is done. You need to post the error stacktrace too. Also it would be great if you can explain a bit what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @RAS I only need to find object in video frames by knowing only info about contour of this object.

Comment: Hey I don't have any knowledge about your question. I just edited your question and made a suggestion to make it as per the standards of SO and to make it more clear so that people can help you out.